# В чём разница между removeFirst() и pop() в Deque?

Tags: java, коллекции, методы

В чём разница между removeFirst() и pop() в Deque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто. Методы эквивалентны. Но есть рекомендация. Если `Deque` используется как двухсторонняя очередь, то предпочтительно использовать `removeFirst()`.
Если `Deque` используется как LIFO-стек (а он подходит для этой задачи), то предпочтительнее использовать `pop()`.

Аналогичные методы: `push` (для стека) - `addFirst` (для очереди), `peek` (для стека) - `peekFirst` (для очереди).

Answer (score 1):

Ничем. Метод `pop()` внутри себя вызывает метод `removeFirst()` и вызов первого или второго является эквивалентным.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно документации, отличие лишь в том, что removeFirst() пробрасывает исключение, если очередь пуста

Comment: Согласно какой документации и какой реализации деки?

Comment: Согласно документации оракл к интерфейсу deque. В вопросе реализация не уточнена, но в тех, что я использовал, это соблюдалось.

Comment: Я вас огорчу, и тот и этот методы выбросят исключение.